# Adding a reference becomes an empty string in Firebase Emulator Suite

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

When I add a reference (`/player_sessions/ZJI1bfIKUBDGiQ9PMBFc`) to one of my collection it becomes an empty string.

Here is the first step of creating the document:
[image]

Here is the result (`player_session_id` is an empty string, not a reference to another document):
[image]

When editing the field with the same data (i.e. the same document path) it updates it correctly:
[image]
[image]

Am I doing something wrong in the **Firebase Emulator Suite** or this is a bug? Without the correct values I can't troubleshoot an `onCreated` trigger I am creating in Firebase Functions.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and show the exact value that you're pasting inside the "Document path"?

Comment: @AlexMamo Updated question with the value I am pasting in

Comment: Seems like a bug. I am facing the same issue.